# After element.replaceWith(contents) how can go back to the original code

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive, replacewith

i have a problem that when i replace an element html i don't know how to go back to the original code before replacement. 
Here is my code. http://jsfiddle.net/Mahmoudbay/o166xg0s/94/  here is the controller.

```
 angular.module('App', [])
 .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.checked = true;
 })
.directive('ngBatchIf', function($compile) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    check: '@'
  },
  controller: function($scope) {},
  link: {
    pre: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('check', function() {
          // After flattening, Angular will still have the first element
          // bound to the old scope, so we create a temporary marker 
          // to store it
          var contents = elm.contents();
          if (scope.check === "true") {
          console.log(scope.check);
          } else {
                            console.log(scope.check);
            elm.replaceWith(contents);
          }
        })
      }

   }
  }
  });
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can create a clone of the original element?

```
var originalElm = elm.clone()
```